# Windows 7 CPU / System meter that ISNT a gadget

Tags: windows, monitoring, overclocking, desktop-gadget

Now that gadgets have been pulled by Microsoft, is there any similar utility that I can use to monitor my system that will sit on the desktop as a gadget does but not present a vulnerability?

Googling "Windows 7 CPU meter" returns hundreds of gadgets, nothing standalone of any decency.

Thanks!

Comment: See this: http://superuser.com/questions/117665/status-app-for-windows

Comment: This will probably be closed as software recommendation question (see [what's on topic on SU](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic)), but try [Rainmeter](http://rainmeter.net/). There are [thousands of miscellaneous meters](http://www.deviantart.com/customization/skins/sysmonitor/rainmeter/) available for free and you can create custom ones. Little ad: try [SimplyRound](http://gronostajo.deviantart.com/art/SimplyRound-352274699) made by me ;)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be a program called "Advanced SystemCare Pro v 6.3" I swear by this program for all kinds of reasons, but you'll see why when you run it... This program has many functions that are useful for cleaning, repairing, or maintaining a computer, but one of them is called the "performance monitor". After installing and running the program, look for it's little icon down on the RIGHT side of the screen, by the clock (it should look like a blue C in a circle)... Your gonna right-click on that icon, and look for an option called "open performance monitor" and there you go... Here's a link to a site with more info and pictures of the various different functions, but take a good look at the pic of the "performance monitor"

http://www.iobit.com/help/asc/doc/top_faqs.html

I hope that works out for you, I know it did for me..!!!